Transit from intl to domestic in Zurich on Swiss
Landing in Zurich from Asia, and need to get to a domestic flight to Geneva 1h15m later. Traveling Swiss all the way. No check in baggage. Is this feasible in today’s traveling conditions? I’ll need to clear customs before my domestic flight. Any insights much appreciated.

The minimum connecting time at ZRH for international to domestic (Schengen) is 40 minutes, so on theory you've got plenty of time.

It depends. Russia, Ukraine, Iran, Israel... all of that can cause diversions and so longer flights, but nobody know what happens tomorrow.

And it's going to depend on your passport and visa. On a Swiss or EU/EEA passport, it'll be quick, but if your nationality is more problematic for them, or there are any complexities or doubts about your visa, you could have a much longer delay. But as mentioned, Swiss Air should do you right.

My shortest time from airplane seat to taxi car seat (leaving the plane, train, immigration, customs) at ZRH airport when arriving from Asia was less than 30 minutes. However, it can take much longer, depending on many factors.

I've often flown from Asia to Zurich and then on to a local Euro city (although not Geneve).  I feel the only answer is "you'll likely be OK, but you're close to the minimum".

If that's a single ticket, this should be fine but there isn't whole lot of room for delays. Most likely you will arrive in Terminal E and will have to take the train to Terminal A/B/D.  This is a bit of nuisance but the train if efficient and fast.

I’ll need to clear customs before my domestic flight

No. You need to go through Schengen immigration in Zurich but you clear customs in Geneva. The latter doesn't matter much since customs in generally a non-event . Immigration depends a bit on your passport. If you can use the automatic gates, its really quick. Lines for manual inspection vary a lot with time of day.
Even if you miss it (through no obvious fault of your own), Swiss will simply put you on the next flight. I think they are operating 9 flights/day on this route with the last one leaving at 10:45pm

And if I had to pick a country to get any scheduling right, I would pick Switzerland.

I think the bottom line is "should be fine but there isn't whole lot of room for delays" is about the best way to put it.

it occurs to me OP should just phone them (I mean today) and ask to be booked on the next shuttle instead as he's nervous about the connection. then you can have a relaxed time at Zurich airport with no stress

I think there's a direct train from Zurich airport straight to Geneva right?  (probably 3 hrs?)  Does anyone know if those direct ones are very frequent? if so an other possibility is do that instead.  depending on what you're up to in Geneva and what area you wanna step out the train in

@Fattie There are three direct trains from ZRH Airport to Geneva each hour, each of them takes about three hours.

3 an hour!  wonderful @nohillside

@Fattie: unless the passenger has status, a last minute rebooking will be extremely expensive, even if it's a flex ticket. There is absolutely no harm in flying it as booked and if that doesn't work, take the next flight for free. This would likely still be faster than taking the train.  Both modes of transportation will give excellent (if different) views.

@Hilmar , sure, my reading of the tone of the OP was that he has not yet bought ticket(s) and was just planning the whole affaire. Also, as I mention, it really just comes down to literally "what business or hotel" he is heading to, and as always the usual forgotten cost of taxis in the actual last step of the journey.  it would be nuts to fly to geneve, if in fact, coincidentally he is going to a meeting in a building just by the gare, etc.  Puttering around like this in Euro cities comes down to the exact location details, don't you think
